# drop box small files upload slowly

Tags: django, dropbox

I have a free dropbox subscription and use it in conjunction with django.

```
def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('')
        file_from = request.FILES['file']
        file_to = '/chat/' + file_from.name 

        # Upload the file
        dbx.files_upload(file_from.read(), file_to)

        # Create a shared link for the uploaded file
        shared_link_metadata = dbx.sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings(file_to)
        url = shared_link_metadata.url

        # Replace ?dl=0 with ?raw=1 in the URL
        url = url.replace('&dl=0', '&raw=1')

        # Create a new Image instance with the shared link
        new_image = Image(image_url=url)
        new_image.save()

        return HttpResponse("Image uploaded and saved successfully!")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Method not allowed", status=405)
```

I have read a lot that uploading large files can be slow however my current upload speed for a file for example ~2MB takes ~3 seconds. From what I've learnt dropbox has no speed settings and tries to upload as fast as possible. However maybe I am still missing something in the app settings?

Comment: Are you timing just the upload to Dropbox or are you timing the upload to Django and then to Dropbox? From your code it looks like you upload to Django first.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat the time I specified is the time from the network tab in the browser devtools.

Comment: Perform some debugging / timing and figure out what exact part is being slow, is it the upload to Django or is it the upload to Dropbox? If it is Django provide information on how you are running Django, are you using the `runserver` command or have you set up a proper production server? As you've currently asked your question it is missing important details.